# Flow: React children array error

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I'm using react@16.0.0-beta.5 and flow-bin@0.54.0

I'm trying to apply flowtype on this component

```
// @flow
class SomeIcon extends Component<{}> {

    render() {
        return (
            <i>
                <img src="" />
                <span>Hello</span>
            </i>
        )
    }

}
```

And flow said

```
14:     <i>
        ^^^ React element `i`
14:     <i>
        ^^^ React children array. This type is incompatible with
children?: React$Node,
           ^^^^^^^^^^ union: undefined | null | boolean | number | string | type application of type `React$Element` | type application of identifier `Iterable`
```

When i remove the `<span>` tag in `<i>` tag, flow goes ok. but if I use multiple children, flow throws error.

What is the problem?

Comment: React children in Flow are annotated as `React$Element<*>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this on my `.flowconfig`

```
[libs]
./node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js.flow
```

`Immutable.js` flow type definitions for `Immutable.Iterable`
has conflict with type definition of
`declare type React$Node = ... | Iterable<React$Node>`

When I updated the Immutable.js to immutable@4.0.0-rc.2, Conflict resolved.

Comment: Exactly my problem! I was going crazy trying to figure this out. Upgrade to immutable rc2 fixed it as well.

Comment: This is correct source of the problem for us but Immutable 4 has a lot of breaking changes from Immutable 3 that we aren't ready for. Any idea on how we can use the existing Immutable 3 flow defs without this error popping up?